# UIPickerView freeze UI

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my application i've a ViewController with two components: a UILabel that will be user like a clock and a UIPickerView that allow user to select an item.

Here there is the code:

```swift
class MyView: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var lblClock: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerAttendance: UIPickerView!
var timer : Timer!
var dateTime: Date!
var pickerData: [String] = ["a","b","c"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dateTime = Date()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: #selector(updateDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()

        pickerAttendance.delegate = self
        pickerAttendance.dataSource = self
   }

    @objc func updateDate(){
        dateTime = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.second, value: 1, to: self.dateTime)
        let s = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: self.dateTime, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.lblClock.text = s
        }
    }

   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
   }
}
```

I instantiate a Date with actual value, and a timer, every seconds the function updates the value of the label.
I explain my problem:
when i scroll the pickerview the label with the timer isn't update but when i release the scroll the label start over the update.

The scrool freeze the ui.

I 've tried to update the label in main thread but problem still appear.
I expect that when i scoll the picker view the label will continue update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your timer in run loop:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dateTime = Date()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: #selector(updateDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)

    timer.fire()

    pickerAttendance.delegate = self
    pickerAttendance.dataSource = self
}
```